# Alfresco share error

Tags: share, alfresco

After installing Alfresco with installer on Win 7 and Ubuntu, I try to login in Share and I get this error:

```
A problem has occurred. 
This page could not be rendered: 
slingshot-login 
Please notify your system administrator.
```

I get this error log for both of them after connecting to Share (http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/page/site-index)

Any suggestion about this?

```
    2011-11-10 21:25:41,261  ERROR [surf.render.RenderService] [http-8080-6] An exception occurred while rendering: slingshot-login
 org.springframework.extensions.surf.exception.RendererExecutionException: Cannot resolve template - may be missing from the definition: template-instance: slingshot-login, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template-instance> 
  <title>Slingshot Login Template</title>  
  <template-type>org/alfresco/global/slingshot-login</template-type> 
</template-instance>
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.processTemplate(RenderService.java:698)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.TemplateInstanceRenderer.calculateComponentDependencies(TemplateInstanceRenderer.java:61)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.TemplateInstanceRenderer.body(TemplateInstanceRenderer.java:118)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:77)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.PageRenderer.body(PageRenderer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:77)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderPage(RenderService.java:763)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView.dispatchPage(PageView.java:419)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView.renderView(PageView.java:258)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.AbstractWebFrameworkView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractWebFrameworkView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.MTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MTAuthenticationFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SSOAuthenticationFilter.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2011-11-11 00:09:13,573  ERROR [surf.render.RenderService] [http-8080-6] An exception occurred while rendering: slingshot-login
 org.springframework.extensions.surf.exception.RendererExecutionException: Cannot resolve template - may be missing from the definition: template-instance: slingshot-login, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<template-instance> 
  <title>Slingshot Login Template</title>  
  <template-type>org/alfresco/global/slingshot-login</template-type> 
</template-instance>

    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.processTemplate(RenderService.java:698)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.TemplateInstanceRenderer.calculateComponentDependencies(TemplateInstanceRenderer.java:61)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.TemplateInstanceRenderer.body(TemplateInstanceRenderer.java:118)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:77)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.PageRenderer.body(PageRenderer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:77)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderPage(RenderService.java:763)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView.dispatchPage(PageView.java:419)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView.renderView(PageView.java:258)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.AbstractWebFrameworkView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractWebFrameworkView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.MTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MTAuthenticationFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SSOAuthenticationFilter.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Alfresco log file contains this log after Alfresco startup:

```
12:20:15,315 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
12:20:15,487 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
12:20:39,567 WARN  [org.alfresco.util.AbstractTriggerBean] Job ehCacheTracerJob is not active/enabled
12:20:50,863 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] Registered template processor Repository Template Processor for extension ftl
12:20:50,873 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] Registered script processor Repository Script Processor for extension js
12:21:07,097 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Schema managed by database dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.
12:21:07,292 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Bypassing schema update checks.
12:21:13,416 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Search' subsystem, ID: [Search, managed, solr]
12:21:14,163 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Search' subsystem, ID: [Search, managed, solr] complete
12:21:23,785 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'thirdparty' subsystem, ID: [thirdparty, default]
12:21:25,776 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'thirdparty' subsystem, ID: [thirdparty, default] complete
12:21:25,776 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'OOoDirect' subsystem, ID: [OOoDirect, default]
12:21:28,919 WARN  [org.alfresco.util.OpenOfficeConnectionTester] An initial OpenOffice connection could not be established.
12:21:28,928 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'OOoDirect' subsystem, ID: [OOoDirect, default] complete
12:21:29,641 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] The Alfresco root data directory ('dir.root') is: C:\Alfresco\alf_data
12:21:29,659 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter] Checking for patches to apply ...
12:21:31,911 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter] No patches were required.
12:21:32,053 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] Found 1 module(s).
12:21:33,252 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] Starting module 'org.alfresco.module.vti' version 1.2.
12:21:35,347 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper] Started module 'ModuleDetails[{module.version=1.2, module.description=Alfresco Vti Extension, module.id=org.alfresco.module.vti, module.repo.version.max=999, module.title=Vti, module.repo.version.min=0, module.installState=INSTALLED, module.installDate=2011-11-10T20:41:27.525+02:00}]' including 0components.
12:21:35,416 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper] Installed module found in distribution: org.alfresco.module.vti
12:21:35,418 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default]
12:21:38,631 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
12:21:39,391 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
12:21:40,041 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default] complete
12:21:40,051 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
12:21:40,411 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default] complete
12:21:40,411 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound]
12:21:40,701 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound] complete
12:21:40,701 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound]
12:21:40,941 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound] complete
12:21:40,941 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'googledocs' subsystem, ID: [googledocs, default]
12:21:41,261 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'googledocs' subsystem, ID: [googledocs, default] complete
12:21:41,261 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default]
12:21:41,391 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default] complete
12:21:41,391 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] Disabled - clear non-missing user usages ...
12:21:41,651 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] Found 0 users to clear
12:21:41,651 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] ... cleared non-missing usages for 0 users
12:21:41,651 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default]
12:21:43,204 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default] complete
12:21:43,816 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] Alfresco JVM - v1.6.0_18-b07; maximum heap size 682,688MB
12:21:43,834 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] Alfresco started (Community). Current version: 4.0.0 (b 3835) schema 5.019. Originally installed version: 4.0.0 (b 3835) schema 5.019.
12:21:44,100 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default]
12:21:44,131 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default] complete
12:21:50,034 INFO  [org.alfresco.module.vti.VtiServer] Vti server started successfully on port: 7070
12:21:50,060 INFO  [org.alfresco.module.vti.VtiServer] Vti server SessionIdManagerWorkerName: jetty1
12:22:00,751 INFO  [org.alfresco.util.OpenOfficeConnectionTester] The OpenOffice connection was re-established.
12:22:17,287 WARN  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Unable to register script classpath:webscripts/org/springframework/extensions/cmis/content.get.desc.xml due to error: 10110000 Web Script document org/springframework/extensions/cmis/content.get.desc.xml is attempting to define the url '/cmis/content:GET' already defined by org/alfresco/cmis/client/content.get.desc.xml
12:22:17,287 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Registered 464 Web Scripts (+1 failed), 731 URLs
12:22:17,287 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Registered 2 Package Description Documents (+0 failed) 
12:22:17,287 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Registered 1 Schema Description Documents (+0 failed) 
12:22:17,292 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntimeContainer] Initialised Repository Web Script Container (in 26962.639ms)
12:22:17,318 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
12:22:17,320 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
```

This can be related with the file `slingshot-application-context.xml`. After installation, we did not change this file. Which parameter we must look at (in this file or another) in order to resolve templates?

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>

<beans>

   <!-- Override the config source to include Web Framework Commons and Share config -->
   <bean id="webframework.configsource" class="org.springframework.extensions.config.source.UrlConfigSource">
      <constructor-arg>
         <list>
            <!-- Spring Web Scripts -->
            <value>classpath:org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/spring-webscripts-config.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:META-INF/spring-webscripts-config-custom.xml</value>
            <value>jar:*!/META-INF/spring-webscripts-config-custom.xml</value>

            <!-- Spring Surf -->
            <value>classpath:org/springframework/extensions/surf/spring-surf-config.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:org/springframework/extensions/surf/spring-surf-config-remote.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:META-INF/spring-surf-config-custom.xml</value>
            <value>jar:*!/META-INF/spring-surf-config-custom.xml</value>

            <!-- Surf Autowire Support -->
            <value>webapp:WEB-INF/surf.xml</value>

            <!-- Common form config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/form-config.xml</value>

            <!-- Share default config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/share-config.xml</value>

            <!-- Share help url config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/share-help-config.xml</value>

            <!-- Share form config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/share-form-config.xml</value>

            <!-- Share Document Library config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/share-documentlibrary-config.xml</value>

            <!-- Share Data List form config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/share-datalist-form-config.xml</value>

            <!-- Share workflow form config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/share-workflow-form-config.xml</value>

            <!-- Share CMIS config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/share-cmis-config.xml</value>

            <!-- Share custom config -->
            <value>classpath:alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml</value>
            <value>jar:*!/META-INF/share-config-custom.xml</value>
         </list>
      </constructor-arg>
   </bean>

   <!-- Override WebScript Messages - add slingshot application messages -->
   <bean id="webscripts.resources" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
      <property name="resourceBundles">
         <list>
            <value>webscripts.messages.webscripts</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.common</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.slingshot</value>
         </list>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Override Web Framework Abstract Handler Mappings -->
   <bean id="webframeworkHandlerMappings" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" abstract="true">
      <property name="urlPathHelper" ref="urlPathHelper" />
      <property name="interceptors">
         <list>
            <ref bean="requestContextInterceptor"/>
            <ref bean="userDashboardInterceptor"/>
            <ref bean="editionInterceptor"/>
         </list>
      </property>
      <property name="mappings">
         <value>
            /system/**=remoteController
            /proxy/**=endpointController
            /resource/**=resourceController
            /feed/**=feedController
            /dologin/**=loginController
            /dologout/**=logoutController
         </value>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Override Logout Controller - to expire Alfresco tickets -->
   <bean id="logoutController" class="org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SlingshotLogoutController">
      <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1" />
      <property name="useExpiresHeader"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="useCacheControlHeader"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="connectorService" ref="connector.service" />
   </bean>

   <!-- Override EndPointProxyController to enable Basic HTTP auth challenge on 401 response -->
   <bean id="endpointController" class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.mvc.EndPointProxyController">
      <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1" />
      <property name="useExpiresHeader"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="useCacheControlHeader"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="configService" ref="web.config" />
      <property name="connectorService" ref="connector.service" />
      <property name="supportedMethods"><null/></property>
      <property name="basicHttpAuthChallenge"><value>true</value></property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Override and configure the remote store for Slingshot -->
   <!-- Point to a specific store on the Alfresco instance -->
   <bean id="webframework.store.remote.abstract" parent="webscripts.remotestore" abstract="true" init-method="init">
      <property name="endpoint">
         <value>alfresco</value>
      </property>
      <property name="api">
         <value>/remoteadm</value><!--remotestore remoteadm-->
      </property>
      <property name="storeId">
         <value>sitestore</value>
      </property>
      <property name="webappPathPrefix">
         <value></value>
      </property>
      <property name="connectorService" ref="connector.service" />
      <property name="connectorProvider" ref="webframework.connector.provider" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="webframework.slingshot.persister.remote" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.persister.PathStoreObjectPersister" parent="webframework.sitedata.persister.abstract">
      <property name="store" ref="webframework.webapp.store.remote" />
      <property name="pathPrefix"><value>alfresco/site-data/${objectTypeIds}</value></property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Surf Model Object Persisters -->
   <bean id="webframework.objects.persister" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.persister.MultiObjectPersister">
      <property name="serviceRegistry" ref="webframework.service.registry" />
      <property name="persisters">
         <list>
            <!-- Slingshot remote store persisters -->
            <ref bean="webframework.slingshot.persister.remote" />

            <!-- Alfresco Legacy Persisters -->
            <ref bean="webframework.sitedata.persister.classpath.alfresco-custom" />
            <ref bean="webframework.sitedata.persister.alfresco-classpath" />

            <!-- Classpath Persister -->
            <ref bean="webframework.sitedata.persister.classpath" />
         </list>
      </property>
      <property name="defaultPersister">
         <ref bean="webframework.slingshot.persister.remote" />
      </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Slingshot Factory beans -->
   <bean id="webframework.factory.user.slingshot" class="org.alfresco.web.site.SlingshotUserFactory" parent="webframework.factory.base" />

   <!-- "no-component" processor -->
   <bean id="webframework.rendition.processor.nocomponent" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.site.EmptyRegionRenderer" />

   <!-- Override WebScript View Resolver - authenticated for admin webscripts via alfresco-feed connector -->
   <bean id="webscriptViewResolver" class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.mvc.WebScriptViewResolver">
      <property name="container" ref="webscripts.container" />
      <property name="authenticatorFactory" ref="webscripts.authenticator.basic" />
   </bean>

   <!-- Override Page View Resolver - to provide access to http req for MT auth support during view name resolution -->
   <bean id="pageViewResolver" class="org.alfresco.web.site.SlingshotPageViewResolver" parent="abstractWebFrameworkViewResolver" />

   <!-- Interceptors -->
   <bean id="editionInterceptor" class="org.alfresco.web.site.EditionInterceptor" parent="abstractWebFrameworkInterceptor" />
   <bean id="userDashboardInterceptor" class="org.alfresco.web.site.UserDashboardInterceptor" parent="abstractWebFrameworkInterceptor" />

   <!--                             -->
   <!--  Web Script Implementations -->
   <!--                             -->

   <!--  I18N resources and messages Web Script -->
   <bean id="webscript.org.springframework.extensions.messages.get" parent="webscript" class="org.alfresco.web.scripts.MessagesWebScript" />
   <bean id="webscript.org.springframework.extensions.messages.post" parent="webscript" class="org.alfresco.web.scripts.MessagesWebScript" />

   <bean id="slingshot.scriptprocessor.dictionaryQuery" parent="baseScriptExtension" class="org.alfresco.web.scripts.DictionaryQuery">
      <property name="extensionName">
         <value>dictionary</value>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="slingshot.scriptprocessor.evaluatorHelper" parent="baseScriptExtension" class="org.alfresco.web.scripts.ActionEvaluatorHelper">
      <property name="extensionName" value="evaluatorHelper"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Extension utils -->
   <bean id="slingshot.evaluator.utility" class="org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotEvaluatorUtil">
      <property name="serviceRegistry" ref="webframework.service.registry" />
   </bean>

   <!-- Module extensibility evaluators -->
   <bean id="site.module.evaluator" class="org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotSiteModuleEvaluator">
      <property name="slingshotEvaluatorUtil" ref="slingshot.evaluator.utility" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="portlet.module.evaluator" class="org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotPortletModuleEvaluator">
      <property name="slingshotEvaluatorUtil" ref="slingshot.evaluator.utility" />
   </bean>

   <!-- Component extensibility evaluators -->
   <bean id="site.component.evaluator" class="org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotSiteComponentElementEvaluator">
      <property name="slingshotEvaluatorUtil" ref="slingshot.evaluator.utility" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="preset.component.evaluator" class="org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotPresetComponentElementEvaluator">
      <property name="slingshotEvaluatorUtil" ref="slingshot.evaluator.utility" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="config.component.evaluator" class="org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotConfigComponentElementEvaluator">
      <property name="slingshotEvaluatorUtil" ref="slingshot.evaluator.utility" />
      <property name="configService" ref="web.config" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="equals.component.evaluator" class="org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotEqualsComponentElementEvaluator"/>
   <bean id="portlet.component.evaluator" class="org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotPortletComponentElementEvaluator">
      <property name="slingshotEvaluatorUtil" ref="slingshot.evaluator.utility" />
   </bean>

   <!-- 
      CMIS beans
   -->
   <bean id="cmis.script" class="org.alfresco.web.cmis.SlingshotCMISScriptParameterFactory" init-method="init">
      <property name="scriptParameterFactoryRegistry" ref="webscripts.web.scriptparameterfactoryregistry" />
      <property name="configService" ref="web.config" />
      <property name="connectorService" ref="connector.service" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="webscript.org.springframework.extensions.cmis.content.get" class="org.springframework.extensions.cmis.CMISContentStreamWebScript" parent="webscript">
      <property name="ScriptParameterFactory" ref="cmis.script" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Startup of Alfresco looks normal, but your exception is a very unusual one. I suspect that the share.war is not properly expanded:

- stop the Alfresco server
- delete the expanded directories `tomcat/webapps/alfresco` and `tomcat/webapps/share`
- delete tomcat/temp/*
- delete tomcat/work/*
- start Alfresco again
- check if http://localhost:8080/alfresco/ is available
- check if http://localhost:8080/share/ is available

Comment: Agreed. I had this same issue because of a problem with the filesystem, and re-deploying Alfresco & Share solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your Alfresco repository has a problem.

If it is the case, you must fix the repository before you can try Share.

Please check your repository at: http://127.0.0.1:8080

If it is indeed not working, check what's wrong in `alfresco.log` and in `tomcat/log`.

Comment: I added alfresco log and slingshot-application-context.xml  ???  Which parameter or file we mut look about this error? Alfresco version is 4.0.b and installed with easy installation (with installer) We did not do any change on configuration